# On iOS, using Intruments, do we have to recompile the program and run it and stop it, and press Record in Instrument to see memory used?

Tags: objective-c, ios

To check the memory usage of an iOS app, say if the code is

```
int n = 1000000;

NSObject *bar = [[NSObject alloc] init];

foo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    [foo addObject: bar];
}
```

we can start Instruments and click on Library on toolbar and chose "Memory Monitor".

But it seems that if I change the code to

```
n = 10;
```

and stop Intruments' Record, and restart Record, the memory use is the same.  I have to stop Record, recompile the code in Xcode, and run it, and stop it, and then come back to Instruments and click Record to see the new memory use?  Is it always needed to go through that many steps, or is there any simpler way, or even if we can use `NSLog` to print memory use right inside `touchesBegan` so whenever we touch the screen, the memory use is printed?

Comment: Not only would you need to recompile, make sure NSZombieEnabled is turned off and you should do memory testing on device. You also need to consider if you're using ARC or 'classic' retain/release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The profile command in Xcode (cmd-I) should do a build and then restart the run in Instruments.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must recompile your source code to executable code using Xcode, Instruments isn't able to do this, but you have to swap back to Xcode to make the change anyway right? You can't make a code edit in Instruments either.

I'm not sure where you got this sequence of steps from. Once your edit is made you need to build, **cmd-B**, then Profile, **cmd-I**.

So that seems like 2 key presses to me..?